# encrypt a properties file for Ibatis

Tags: java, swing, ibatis, netbeans6.8, mybatis

I have a properties file containg the database username/password which i used it to manage ibatis connection with the database.

What is the best way to encrypt this properties file to be secure.
Actually I am using netbeans 6.8. Is there a way to encrypt this properties file while making packaging for the project, or any other way to prevent others to see the database credentials?

I am using ibatis to connect to database in a java desktop application

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to remove the temptation or make it impossible for the users to find the username/password to manually connect to the database?

If you just want to remove the temptation, you can off course encrypt the file. MyBatis (*I see you tagged your question `mybatis` and `ibatis` so I'll assume MyBatis in my code*) does not offer an out of the box way of using encrypted credentials, but you can intervene in code where the credentials are used and do your decryption there. You just have to create a custom data source factory.

Assuming you have a data source like this:

```
<dataSource type="UNPOOLED">
    <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://someServer/someDB" />
    <property name="username" value="${user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</dataSource>
```

with a properties file for the keys:

```
user=JohnDoe
password=p@$$word
```

you can encrypt the file and then create a custom data source factory like so (**make sure you extend the right one: pooled, unpooled etc**):

```
package com.test;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.ibatis.datasource.unpooled.UnpooledDataSourceFactory;

public class CustomDataSourceFactory extends UnpooledDataSourceFactory {
    @Override
    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        String user = null;
        String pass = null;

        // decrypt the file, use some fancy obfuscation, connect somewhere to get
        // the username and password dynamically at startup, whatever...
        //
        // user = "JohnDoe";
        // pass = "p@$$word";

        properties.put("username", user);
        properties.put("password", pass);
        super.setProperties(properties);
    }
}
```

Your data source will then change to:

```
<dataSource type="com.test.CustomDataSourceFactory">
    <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://someServer/someDB" />
</dataSource>
```

And now the users can't see the credentials anymore.

But note that **the above won't protect the username/password**. Whatever you choose to eliminate the temptation (encryption, obfuscation, some sophisticated algorithm etc) the thing is that **your user has everything he needs to reverse the process right there on his machine** (decrypt key, extract the archive, decompile code, reverse engineering etc).

To **make it impossible** to retrieve the username/password, move iBatis/myBatis to an application server; i.e. transform your [thick client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_client) into a [thinner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client) one. You obtain a decoupling between the windows application and the database. Your application server will run all the database queries based on commands received by the windows application.

In this case, the windows application will no longer be running the queries itself so it won't need the database credentials at all; the database credentials will be stored on the application server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IBatis in a web application?  If so, you should set up the database access details in the web container, not the application.  Your application would then access the database via the container (Tomcat, GlassFish, Websphere etc.) and have no concern about security.

You basically want to set up a JNDI DataSource - something that exists in the container framework and not your application.  I wouldn't want database access details in a properties file if I could help it.

Comment: Hello Ewald, thanks for your reply but i am using ibatis with a java desktop application and not a web application. As you said if i have a container like tomcat it will be included in it. But in my case i don't have. Any idea how to do this in java desktop application?

Comment: Hi, the only other option then is to use some encryption scheme in your application encrypt and decrypt the text file. That will fool the casual hacker, but not a determined one. I have used encrypted ZIP files for this exact purpose in the past, not an ideal solution, but it worked in the context and was secure enough for the given scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, keep in mind, that to encrypt password, you need a key and you will have to store that key somewhere. That is the case for any solution you choose for encryption and applies to application server as well.

That means that key safety should be considered somehow, e.g. security can be setup on UNIX account level or something like that.

here is good example of the code which encrypts data and generates a key:

http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesString.html

And here is how to save a load key from file:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/TripleDES.htm

Comment: I have a java desktop application which i am using ibatis for database connection. In a properties file i set the username and password of the database.but in this solution anyone can open the jar file of the application and open the properties file and then know the uersname and password. The problem is that when i first run my application i need to have the username and password to connect to the database...

Comment: Ask a user for username and password? Or I could not understand the case clearly...

Comment: The user that uses this application does not know anything about the database...and he don't know the username and password of the database. I just want to secure my application, so if he or someone else someone opens the jar file or extract it, he should not know the username/passwrod cz he may change manually in the database

Answer (score 0):

I've also searching for same problem of securing Database.properties file and found an easy way: 
If u know that the user of your application will be connected to the internet than without using encryption-decryption just host your properties file on any free file hosting site that can provide you with two major properties:

1. that can provide you direct link to the file.
2. and, that can provide you facilities to edit the same file whenever you want to change it.

One of the solution that i am using is [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), You can watch a tutorial for using its public folder property [Here](http://www.technabled.com/2009/07/how-to-host-css-and-javascript-files.html)
... Hope that will solve your problem as it solve mine :)

Comment: The `link` you will use to retrieve the properties from `.properties` file will be just in your compiled `class`,, which is not readily breachable..

Comment: `.properties file will be just in your compiled class,, which is not readily breachable..`. A jar can be unzipped, a class can be decompiled and the link extracted and properties file retrieved. There is only one way to make it safe, move iBatis away from the client.